# Notificaciones con firebase + php

Tags: php, android, firebase

Hola ayuda  lo que quiero es lo siguiente estoy tratando de enviar una notificación a los usuarios de una app yo se que eso se realiza por medio de los token pero esa es mi inquietud  no quiero enviarlas por token quiero enviarla a todos los usuarios que tienen instalada la app en su dispositivo como por decir por paquete como se hace desde la consola de firebase .. 
aqui esta mi codigo

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR_FIREBASE_API_ACCESS_KEY' );
$registrationIds = [];
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => $valorDescripcion,
    'title'     => $valorTipo,
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'notification'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podés hacer es enviar los mensajes por temas.
Creas un tema y en la app hacés que todos se suscriban a ese mismo tema.
Luego, desde el php, cuando mandás el mensaje lo mandas al tema en lugar de a dispositivos específicos.

Esto te permite evitar el tema de registrar tokens en un server y mantener esa lista actualizada.

En el php el mensaje quedaría:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

(En lugar de los tokens va el 'to:'. foo-bar es el nombre del tema en el ejemplo vos pones el tuyo.)

[En este link de Firebase Cloud Messaging están las instrucciones.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging?hl=es)

Comment: no había pensado en eso muchas gracias tiene toda la razón

Comment: una ultima pregunta como quedaría el código en php que enviaría en esta parte **$registrationIds = [];**

Comment: Ahi lo agregué a la respuesta. Lo cambias por "to" con valor "/topics/<tu_tema>"